# How does openport.io open up services like SSH even though I am behind a firewall?

Tags: ip

There is a service out there, http://www.openport.io, which allows a computer to open up services, such as SSH and Web servers, to the rest of the world even if the computer is behind a firewall.

I am currently deploying Raspberry pi machines in my clients' homes which are almost always behind firewalls with dynamic IPs.

How does openports do this? Are there any alternatives?

I am asking about this because openports is poorly documented and they are not responsive to emails.

NOTE: No-IP solves the dynamic ip problem. It does not help you get around the firewall.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking, consumer-grade devices, applications, and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

The "server" you want to make available makes an outbound connection to openport.io and maintains an open socket.  When the "client" connects to a specified port on openport.io this connection is tied back to the original socket. It's basically a cross-connect, potentially with the added ability to multiplex multiple connections across the single "server" socket (didn't dig in too deeply).

Ultimately it's just tying together two sockets - so essentially just a special-case proxy server.

Answer (score -2):

I found NGROK and they have much better documentation.